# Create image from VMWare Linux guest

Tags: linux, debian-squeeze, vmware-workstation, iso

I have a Debian Linux installed as a VMWare guest.

I want to create an .iso (or .img) from this installation, from which I can create a server installation.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked online or tried VMWare documentation?

Comment: Also, what is the purpose of this iso image? Should it just be a complete backup of the system, or should it be able to be used as an customized installation image, or ...?

Comment: Yes, I looked online but failed to get a solution. The purpose of the .iso is to use it as an installation image.

Comment: If this is an installation image why not just use a VMware Template? Or is this to install on a physical host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I've always done this is just the same way I backup my real world Linux partitions. Linux has dozens of ways to do this but you'll want something which is capable of restoring to different hardware (so anything which does an EXACT disk image isn't going to work). One solution which will is:

http://clonezilla.org/

If you want to use clonezilla, here is a tutorial: http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/clonezilla.html

It basically works exactly the same in a VM as it does on a physical machine. You'll need to mount the image to your VM using the hardware setup screen in VMWare to simulate having a boot disk in at bootup.

To use an image file in the virtual machine, follow these steps:

- On the host computer, create an ISO image of your installation CD. Save the ISO image file in any location accessible to your host. For best performance, place this image on the host computer's hard drive.
- With the virtual machine powered off, open the Configuration Editor (choose Settings > Configuration Editor), and select the virtual CD-ROM device.
- On Linux host machines, change the Device Type to CD-ROM image and enter the path and filename of the ISO image.
- On Windows host machines, select Use ISO image, then browse to the image file and select it.
- Power on the virtual machine.

Comment: Do you have a link to some documentation on how to create a clone of a Debian VMware guest?

Comment: I've updated the answer with more details on the cloning process.